# how to add data to one table from a large number of tables

Tags: gspread

I have problem with my project. I have more then 45 tables with 6 sheets in them. My script must find same rows from that tables and another table, then it must insert that row in the table for same rows. I finished it but it have one problem. Standard number of quota is 100 per 100seconds. I tried to fix the problem by time.sleep(1) after requests , but i have more than 45 tables and it's take much time to find all same rows

```
if i == x:
    dopler_cell_list = dopler.range(f'A{str(len(lol2) + length)}:AI{str(len(lol2) + length)}')
    time.sleep(1)
    for cell in dopler_cell_list:
        cell.value = output_cell_list[count].value
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1
```

How i can make it faster?

Comment: You could implement your own class to limit the rate at which you call the api or check out [ratelimit](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/)

Comment: it's take much time to find all same rows , because standard number of quota per second is 1